# How to remove Google map markers in Vue?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, vuejs3

I'm using Google API to display a map, markers, and polygons.
When I add a new marker, the previous markers are not gone.

I save the map, markers & polygons inside my data state.

```
data() {
    return {
    google: window.google,
    map: null,
    activeInfoWindow: null,
    polygons: [],
    markers: []
    }
},
```

I tried to remove the previous markers with marker.setMap(null) before showing new markers

```
filtersResults: function (filterResults) {
    // REMOVE PREVIOUS ACTIVE MARKER
    this.markers.map((marker) => marker.setMap(null))
},
```

I tried to empty the markers array too. Nothing happens, the markers still show on the map.
[image]
[image]

The setMap is not undefined, this is the result when I'm console.log(marker.setMap)

```
ƒ (c){try{this.set(a,b(c))}catch(d){_.Pe(_.Oe("set"+_.Bf(a),d))}}
```

```
  data() {
      return {
        google: window.google,
        map: null,
        activeInfoWindow: null,
        polygons: [],
        markers: []
      }
    },
    async mounted() {
      const { LatLng, Map, MapTypeId } = this.google.maps
        this.map = new Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new LatLng(process.env.INITIAL_LAT, process.env.INITIAL_LNG),
            mapTypeId: MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        })
    },
    watch: {
      filtersResults: function (filterResults) {
        // REMOVE PREVIOUS ACTIVE MARKER
        this.markers.map((marker) => marker.setMap(null))
        this.markers = []
      },
      assets: {
        handler: function (newValue) {
          const { map } = this
          if (isNotNullAndUndefined(newValue) && map) {
            
            // ! GENERATE MARKER IN HERE
            this.markers = newValue.map((value) => {
              const { location } = value
              return this.generateMarkers({
                latitude: dotFormat(location.lat),
                longitude: dotFormat(location.lng),
                details: value
              })
            })
          }
        },
        immediate: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      generateMarkers({ latitude, longitude, details }) {
        const { map, google } = this
        const { LatLng, Marker } = google.maps

        const marker = new Marker({
          position: new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          draggable: false
        })

        marker.setMap(map)
        return marker
      },
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When we store the `Markers` in the `markers` array, vue.js 3 converts them to `Proxy` objects.
That causes a problem when we later call `Proxy.setMap(null)`; Google Maps somehow doesn't like that, probably because the Proxy object is not `===` the original `Marker` object added to the map initially.

The workaround I found was to use `toRaw()` before using any Google Maps objects that were converted to `Proxy` objects:

```js
import {toRaw} from 'vue';

this.markers.map((marker) => toRaw(marker).setMap(null))
```

Comment: This saved us a lot of investigation, thank you!  In the end we went with excluding our `markers` from the component's `data()` method so Vue doesn't make it reactive - it's constructed with a `.map` on a prop anyway so there was no need to initialise it separately, and since we only need to react to changes on the prop and not the `markers` array there doesn't seem to be any benefit to it being reactive in the first place.

Comment: thanks... this is really helpful to remove markers

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I was about to lose my mind on this.

Comment: Is this the same with google  marker clusterer as well? I cannot get code from the docs to work in vue3?

Comment: @Yewla Yes, very probably all Google Maps objects will need this, when used in Vue.

Comment: @Yewla Did you find a solution? The documentation of markerClusterer says, that you have to use this.markerClusterer?.clearMarkers() when you want to clear them. But this also only works with vue2 and not with vue3.

Comment: @tomson  In Vue 3 script setup mode I do it this way (toRaw is your new best friend)

    if (toRaw(l_cluster.value) !== null) {
      // hideGatewayCluster()
      hideCluster(toRaw(l_cluster.value))
    }

const hideCluster = cluster => {
  if (cluster) {
    // console.log(`cluster ${cluster}`);
    // check if cluster is already initialized
    cluster.clearMarkers() // remove all markers from cluster
    cluster.setMap(null) // hide the cluster
  }
}