# How to delete Google Maps markers in Vue 3 composition API (JS Gmaps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to follow the google maps documentation [google maps remove marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) and I cant seem to delete markers how they say to.

I have seen many posts about this on various sites but to no avail. The map opens with one marker already placed, and there is a simple function to remove that marker. When I click the button, I get no error and the marker remains.

*My only guess is that I am not accessing the marker obj correctly?*

**Using Vue3, composition API, straight JS google maps api, no extra modules**

```
<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import { ref, onMounted, } from "vue";

import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";

const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GAPI;

const loader = new Loader({ apiKey: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }); // load APIKEY

const mapDiv = ref(null); // define divref to populate the map

let map = ref(null); // map object

let markers = ref([]);


onMounted(async () => { //create map
  await loader.load();
  map.value = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, {
    // center: currPos.value,
    center: { lat: 40, lng: -80 },
    zoom: 7,
  });

  const initialMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 40.785091, lng: -73.968285 },
    map: map.value,
    title: "PLEASE WORK SIR",
  });

  markers.value.push(initialMarker);
});

const removeMarker = () => {

  console.log('remove marker');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.value.length; i++) {
    console.log('i', markers.value[i]);
    markers.value[i].setMap(null);
    markers.value = []
  }

};


</script>

<template>
  <div style="overflow-y: hidden">
    <v-btn @click="removeMarker">Delete all markers</v-btn>

    <div ref="mapDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Check is the problem persists if you don't make Markers reactive. I had problems with reactive Marker objects. Making them reactive has brocken some functionality in my app, and it was fixed when I've removed  reactivity and used raw Marker objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874504/12020486

Vue 3 was converting google objects array into proxy objects